# 'House was haunted by ghost' or 'house was haunting by ghost' - is there a difference?

Tags: meaning

Could you explain me a difference between usage of *haunting* and *haunted*? [Wiktionary says](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/haunt) me:

> haunt (verb) - To inhabit, or visit frequently (most often used in reference to ghosts).

So this is my way of understanding:
haunt - visit frequently (again and again, daily or weekly possible)
haunted - visited (?) frequently - ghost (someone else) used to visit house frequently
haunting - visiting frequently - ghost was visited house regularly in past (again and again, daily or weekly possible)

I'm really confused with all these -ing and -ed relatively to `haunt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"(The) House was haunted by **a** ghost" is the only one that makes sense. You need to refresh your English grammar, that's all. Namely, on Active vs Passive Voice.

Comment: "A ghost was haunting the house." - https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/haunting

Comment: Yup :-)  That's an example of an Active Voice, Past Continuous tense. While "was haunted by a ghost" is Passive voice, Past Simple tense. Both are perfectly correct. But not "house was haunting **by a ghost**" as in your original post. I again suggest you to take any book on English grammar (in your language) and read about tenses and voices. Such books usually give info in a systematised way and this would really help you to understand these -ed, -ing stuff.

Comment: It is not a problem to understand passive/active vouice for me, I've got a problem with active/passive only relatively to `haunt`. Ok, it was really dumb mistake to say `house was haunting by a ghost`, but while "haunt" mean "visit frequently", why don't we say... it seems that I realized my mistake while typing a message :-)